# iOS: Can I use Game Center match maker with Unity RPC?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center, multiplayer

Can I use the gamecenter funcionality to find a player for a multiplayer game and then setup a Unity RPC match with that player?

I read in the Game Center documentation that there exists funcionality to find the players for a match and then use my own code to setup the match and use my own networking code. But I can't find any code sample to make that work with unity RPC.